# jax-rs Response entity class

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

I'm trying to create a jax-rs client which posts an xml as object and receives an xml on the response body from the server.  The code is as below:

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
..
TravelRequest tr = ...
..
WebClient client = WebClient.create(url);
client.type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
javax.ws.rs.core.Response r = client.post(tr);
Object response = r.getEntity();
```

The java type of the response object is sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream
Is it possible to get an object of TravelRequest type instead of reading the xml from input stream? Someone knows any example of it? I can also use spring to configure my client.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it is done.

```
TravelRequest travelRequest = client.post(tr, TravelRequest.class);
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `WebClient` the wrong way. Methods  like [`accept`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html#accept%28javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType...%29) and [`type`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html#type%28javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%29) dont' *alter* the `WebClient` but return the updated Client

So the correct usage is:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(url);
Response response = client.type(...).accept(...).post(tr);
```

The [`Response.getEntity()`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getEntity%28%29) can then be used to extract the response.

CXF supports [various forms of data binding](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/databindings.html) that you can use to map the response body to your classes.

Comment: I see from the link that JAXB is the default for binding response body. How can I use it?